# Reading from brackets and converting it to an array

Tags: c, arrays

First of all I must say that I'm quite fresh to programming in C and I just can't overcome one of my problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    struct huh{
        char cos[];
    };
    huh(abbcabd);
    printf("%c",cos[3]);
}
```

I want the output to be "b" in this case but I don't need to comment that this code doesn't work at all.

I want to enter some text into huh() brackets so then it would be converted to an array or something similar, so I could use the order of entered letters later.

It's important to me that usage of it would look just at it looks now - simply typing anything into those brackets.

So how it should look like?

Comment: Did you ever read a book about C? This is not C.

Comment: First of all, `cos` is a reserved name, so you can't use it. Second, you need to put a positive number between the braces to define an array.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - `cos` is not a reserved name

Comment: @JerryCoffin: there are only a few reserved words in C. `cos` is not one of them.

Comment: @Jongware: Actually, there are an *infinite* number of reserved words in C. See the library introduction and "future library directions" for some of the patterns (e.g., all names starting with `str`, `is`, `to`, macros starting with `E` followed by another upper case letter or a digit, and the list goes on and on).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: *libraries* don't count. I can give any name to any function and stuff it into a library (even `cos`) but *not* one of the reserved words such as `default` or `return`.

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, libraries *do* count. Names reserved for the library are still reserved. The standard doesn't differentiate between names reserved for the library, and names reserved for the compiler proper (e.g., "knowledge" of the library is often "baked into" the compiler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define huh(x) cos = #x

char *cos;

int main(){
    struct huh{//unuse type
        char dummy;
        char cos[];
    };

    huh(abbcabd);

    printf("%c",cos[3]);//print c, array origin 0 in C
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So now I see that my problem was that I should have used macro instead of struct.